# How to call Stored Procedure from a Snowflake Response Translator?

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a response translator:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION response_translator(EVENT OBJECT)
RETURNS OBJECT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT AS
'
var responses =[];
if (EVENT.body.error!=null){
for(i=0; i<6;i++){
if (i==0){
let result=[i, EVENT.body]
responses[i] = result
}
else{
let result = [i,null]
responses[i] = result
}
}
return { "body": { "data" :responses } };
}
else{
return { "body": EVENT.body };
}
```

Here `i` has to iterate over the number of rows present in the table calling the external function that uses this response translator.

To programmatically get the value `i`, I use a stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure get_row_count(table_name VARCHAR)
  returns float not null
  language javascript
  as
  $$
  var row_count = 0;
  var sql_command = "select count(*) from " + TABLE_NAME;
  var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
         {
         sqlText: sql_command
         }
      );
  var res = stmt.execute();
  res.next();
  row_count = res.getColumnValue(1);
  return row_count;
  $$
  ;
```

which I can then call using   `call get_row_count('my_table');`

How do I call the stored procedure within the response translator and store the output of the stored procedure so that I can replace the hardcoded value over which `i` has to iterate?

Answer (score 0):

Create get_row_count as a function and include it in the call to response_translator e.g.

```
Call response_translator(evt, get_row_count(table_name))
```

Comment: What is evt in your code? Also, how would I run the select count (*) query that has to be included within the get_row_count function since snowflake objects do not exist automatically for functions?

Comment: evt is the EVENT object you have in your code. I have no idea what you mean by “snowflake objects do not exist automatically for functions”. You need to write a UDF that takes a table name as an input parameter, runs a query to count the records in that table and then returns that count. You already have all this code, except you’ve written it as a SP and you need to write it as a UDF, which is a trivial change